# Not contained in GROUP BY or Aggregate function SQL Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

That's the error that I'm getting for this SQL code. I don't know the best way to go about fixing it.

```
SELECT
    muo.VehicleReferenceCode as REF#,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), muo.ActualDeliveryDate, 101) as 'Date In',
    vd.Model as Model,
    muo.DealerCategoryCode as 'Cat.',
    v.PurchaseSourceVendorCode as Vendor,
    muo.VendorCost + muo.FactoryOptionsCost as 'VEH Cost',
    muo.FreightCostAmt as Freight,
    muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost as 'Trans Cost',
    SUM(woeid.h_ListPrice) - SUM(woeid.DiscountAmt) as 'Int P&A Charge',
    SUM(woeld.RegularLaborAmt) - SUM(woeld.DiscountAmt) as 'Int Labor Charge',
    muo.VendorCost 
      + muo.FactoryOptionsCost 
      + muo.FreightCostAmt 
      + muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost 
      + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost 
      + SUM(woeid.h_ListPrice) 
      - SUM(woeid.DiscountAmt) 
      + SUM(woeld.RegularLaborAmt) 
      - SUM(woeld.DiscountAmt)                 as 'VEH Total'
FROM MajorUnitOrder muo 
     INNER JOIN Vehicle v
        ON muo.VehicleIdentificationNum = v.VehicleIdentificationNum 
     JOIN VehicleDesignator vd
       ON v.VehicleDesignatorCode = vd.VehicleDesignatorCode 
     JOIN WorkOrder wo
       ON v.VehicleIdentificationNum = wo.VehicleIdentificationNum 
     JOIN WorkOrderEventItemDetail woeid
       ON wo.WorkOrderCode = woeid.WorkOrderCode 
     JOIN WorkOrderEventLaborDetail woeld
       ON woeid.WorkOrderCode = woeld.WorkOrderCode
```

Comment: Where is the Group By clause?

Comment: Now that I added a Group By my sum is getting messed up.
I tested SUM(woeid.h_ListPrice) - SUM(woeid.DiscountAmt) as 'Int P&A Charge' by doing the query SELECT SUM(h_ListPrice) - SUM(DiscountAmt) FROM WorkOrderEventItemDetail WHERE WorkOrderCode = '12002'. I want it to return that info for each WorkOrderCode though. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use the aggregate function `SUM` with other fields when you have a `GROUP BY` clause in your query

Comment: I'm having issues though when I add the GROUP BY. More info in my comment on the Original Post.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post the schema for the two tables.    From the looks of it, mui doesn't really have to be aggregated--why not just `woeid.h_ListPrice - woeid.DisCountAmt AS 'Int P&A Charge"`?   What are you summing?   Are there multiple MajorUnitOrders for each Vehicle?

Comment: No, there are multiple workordereventitemdetails for each majorunitorder. I'll use the aliases to describe the relations. muo:v:vd:wo are all 1 to 1. v connects to wo via the vehicle's VIN. Now, the WorkOrderCode in wo can link to many woeid entries. I need these entries to have the h_ListPrice summed up and then the sum of all the DiscountAmt subtracted from it. I hope this explains it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to include aggregate functions in your select statement, then you need to make sure all the non-aggregate functions are included in a GROUP BY statement.

In this case, you'd need to add a GROUP BY clause that includes every single line except for 'Int P&A Charge' and 'Int Labor Charge', as they use the aggregate SUM() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could approach the query:

```
SELECT
    muo.VehicleReferenceCode                     AS REF#,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), muo.ActualDeliveryDate, 101) AS 'Date In',
    vd.Model                                     AS Model,
    muo.DealerCategoryCode                       AS 'Cat.',
    v.PurchaseSourceVendorCode                   AS Vendor,
    muo.VendorCost + muo.FactoryOptionsCost      AS 'VEH Cost',
    muo.FreightCostAmt                           AS Freight,
    muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost 
      + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost              AS 'Trans Cost',
    COALESCE(ORDR.ListPriceSum, 0.0) 
        - COALESCE(ORDR.DiscountAmtSum, 0.0)     AS 'Int P&A Charge',
    COALESCE(LABOR.LaborAmtSum, 0.0)
        - COALESCE(LABOR.LaborDiscountSum, 0.0)  AS 'Int Labor Charge',
    muo.VendorCost 
      + muo.FactoryOptionsCost 
      + muo.FreightCostAmt 
      + muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost 
      + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost 
      + COALESCE(ORDR.ListPriceSum, 0.0)
      - COALESCE(ORDR.DiscountAmtSum, 0.0)
      + COALESCE(LABOR.LaborAmtSum, 0.0)
      - COALESCE(LABOR.LaborDiscountSum, 0.0)    AS 'VEH Total'
FROM MajorUnitOrder muo 
     INNER JOIN Vehicle v
        ON muo.VehicleIdentificationNum = v.VehicleIdentificationNum 
     JOIN VehicleDesignator vd
       ON v.VehicleDesignatorCode = vd.VehicleDesignatorCode 
     JOIN WorkOrder wo
       ON v.VehicleIdentificationNum = wo.VehicleIdentificationNum 
     LEFT JOIN 
     (
         SELECT WorkOrderCode
                SUM(h_ListPrice    AS ListPriceSum,
                SUM(DiscountAmt)   AS DiscountAmtSum,
           FROM WorkOrderEventItemDetail
                GROUP BY WorkOrderCode
     ) ORDR
       ON ORDR.WorkOrderCode = wo.WorkOrderCode
     LEFT JOIN
     (
         SELECT WorkOrderCode,
                SUM(RegularLaborAmt) AS LaborAmtSum,
                SUM(DiscountAmt)     AS LaborDiscountSum
           FROM WorkOrderEventLaborDetail
                GROUP BY WorkOrderCode
     ) LABOR
       ON LABOR.WorkOrderCode = wo.WorkOrderCode
```

Comment: Thanks Curt! Really appreciate it. If you could explain why you did what you did that'd be great. If I'm understanding it correctly you do the JOIN of the subquery in order to get around the aggregation issues I was having? I don't understand what the COALESCE does though, does it just ensure against NULL values? Neat code though, works great!

Comment: Yes:  I'm doing the aggregation for the values in a subquery, where it can be better optimized (and the SQL becomes cleaner).   The COALESCE is because the subqueries are `OUTER JOIN`ed, and if they end up containing a NULL value, they would "pollute" your calculations, turning them NULL as well.

Comment: Hey Curt, suppose I was wrong and every once in a while there are two WorkOrders for the same VIN. I need to add up the sums from both the workorders and subtract them to get a grand total in that case. What would be the best way to do that? Another subquery?

Comment: @Vap0r   That sounds right.   Ping me if you have any problems.

Comment: Alright. My problem right now is that the next thing I would want to GROUP BY would be the VehicleReferenceCode so that I could SUM  the PriceSum and DiscountSum fields. Unfortunately VehicleReferenceCode is only available in WorkOrder and in order to include it I'd run into aggregation issues again. @Curt

Comment: You'll have to join them in the subselect to get the grouping  & aggregation, then, it sounds like.   Can you post the schemas (and cardinalities) for *ALL* the tables in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Since the aggregate SUM is used in the query, you will need to add a GROUP BY clause to tell the SQL engine how the results should be summed.  For example by Model, Dealer, etc.  Essentially it is missing the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    muo.VehicleReferenceCode as REF#,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), muo.ActualDeliveryDate, 101) as 'Date In',
    vd.Model as Model,
    muo.DealerCategoryCode as 'Cat.',
    v.PurchaseSourceVendorCode as Vendor,
    muo.VendorCost + muo.FactoryOptionsCost as 'VEH Cost',
    muo.FreightCostAmt as Freight,
    muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost as 'Trans Cost',
    SUM(woeid.h_ListPrice) - SUM(woeid.DiscountAmt) as 'Int P&A Charge',
    SUM(woeld.RegularLaborAmt) - SUM(woeld.DiscountAmt) as 'Int Labor Charge',
    muo.VendorCost + muo.FactoryOptionsCost + muo.FreightCostAmt + muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost + SUM(woeid.h_ListPrice) - SUM(woeid.DiscountAmt) + SUM(woeld.RegularLaborAmt) - SUM(woeld.DiscountAmt) as 'VEH Total'
FROM MajorUnitOrder muo INNER JOIN Vehicle v
    ON muo.VehicleIdentificationNum = v.VehicleIdentificationNum JOIN VehicleDesignator vd
    ON v.VehicleDesignatorCode = vd.VehicleDesignatorCode JOIN WorkOrder wo
    ON v.VehicleIdentificationNum = wo.VehicleIdentificationNum JOIN WorkOrderEventItemDetail woeid
    ON wo.WorkOrderCode = woeid.WorkOrderCode JOIN WorkOrderEventLaborDetail woeld
    ON woeid.WorkOrderCode = woeld.WorkOrderCode
GROUP BY
    muo.VehicleReferenceCode,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), muo.ActualDeliveryDate, 101),
    vd.Model,
    muo.DealerCategoryCode,
    v.PurchaseSourceVendorCode,
    muo.VendorCost + muo.FactoryOptionsCost,
    muo.FreightCostAmt,
    muo.TransferredPDIPartsCost + muo.TransferredPDILaborCost
```

Comment: Thanks, the TransferredPDIPartsCost and LaborCost also have to be individually declared, but other than that this is spot on. Is this really the best way to do it? It seems kind of excessive.

Comment: Wait nevermind, now that I added the group by my sums aren't coming out right. I tried the query individually and it worked, I just had to specify a WHERE WorkOrderCode = VALUE. Is there a way to do this? Maybe I'm not understanding how SUM works.

Comment: Lots of questions -- so these are all individual answers: 1) Any time you aggregate (e.g., use functions like SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.), you *must* use `GROUP BY`.  2) Not sure what you mean by trying the query individually...  3) As for a WHERE clause -- yes, you can use one.  4) You could include `WorkOrderCode` in your SELECT & GROUP BY, or just in the GROUP BY -- either way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be that instead column, you can use subquery to fetch value from table based on current key in JOIN, in that case you can avoid putting that columns in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply aggregate functions on some columns of the select columns list then you should use group by clause on columns which are not applied by aggregate functions

```
Example
Right Query :--
Select dept_id,sum(sal) from employee group by dept_id 

Wrong Query :-
Select dept_id,sum(sal) from employee
```